# Which recursive function will cost less memory?

Tags: c++, recursion

```
void func(int depth){
    if(depth== 0) return;
    int number(12345);
    cout << number; //it does something with number
    func(--depth);
}
void func2(int depth){
    if(depth== 0) return;
    {
        int number(12345);
        cout << number; //it does something with number
    }
    func2(--depth);
}
void main(){
    func(10); //will this function cost more memory?
    func2(10);//will this function cost less memory?
}
```

Hi. I have two functions here. Will func2 cost less memory because its number(12345) is encapsulated by "{}" so that by the time func2 calls the next iteration, number(12345) can go outside the scope and disappear?

I believe func will cost more because its number(12345) is not outside of the scope even when it reaches the next iteration?

Comment: Both functions are exactly the same.

Comment: You never actually *use* `number`, so any decent compiler will optimize it away entirely in both versions when building with optimizations enabled.

Comment: And there's no "iterative" in any of the functions. Both are *recursive* (although that could be seen as a kind of loop, so in a way they are iterative but not in the meaning of actual loop statements).

Comment: so I changed name to recursive because it is the right term.

Comment: @JesperJuhl it was an example, in practice, I do stuff like generating stuff then displaying it, let me fix the code so that it does something

Comment: @Blue Bug with your edit `number` still only lives and is used within the current stack frame. The nested scope is refundant and irrelevant. As @Some programmer dude said; the two functions are functionally identical (and the compiler knows this and will generate the same code).

Comment: Apart from the compiler optimizing away your `number` (for various reasons), it can also use tail-recursion so both `func(10)` and `func(10000000)` use the same amount of memory.

Comment: Should be the same. In default c calling convention, caller is doing final stack adjustment. Inside the function modern compilers would generate stack frame adjustments only once.

Comment: The generated GIMPLE and LLVM IR are identical even at `-O0`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming we have AMD/Intel x86_64 architecture and our compiler is GCC.

Lets took assembly output (-O2 -S) and analyze:

```
func:
.LFB1560:
    pushq   %rsi
    .seh_pushreg    %rsi
    pushq   %rbx
    .seh_pushreg    %rbx
    subq    $40, %rsp
    .seh_stackalloc 40
    .seh_endprologue
    movl    %ecx, %ebx
    testl   %ecx, %ecx
    je  .L3
    movq    .refptr._ZSt4cout(%rip), %rsi
    .p2align 4,,10
.L5:
    movl    $12345, %edx
    movq    %rsi, %rcx
    call    _ZNSolsEi
    subl    $1, %ebx
    jne .L5
.L3:
    addq    $40, %rsp
    popq    %rbx
    popq    %rsi
    ret
    .seh_endproc

func2:
.LFB2046:
    pushq   %rsi
    .seh_pushreg    %rsi
    pushq   %rbx
    .seh_pushreg    %rbx
    subq    $40, %rsp
    .seh_stackalloc 40
    .seh_endprologue
    movl    %ecx, %ebx
    testl   %ecx, %ecx
    je  .L10
    movq    .refptr._ZSt4cout(%rip), %rsi
    .p2align 4,,10
.L12:
    movl    $12345, %edx
    movq    %rsi, %rcx
    call    _ZNSolsEi
    subl    $1, %ebx
    jne .L12
.L10:
    addq    $40, %rsp
    popq    %rbx
    popq    %rsi
    ret
    .seh_endproc
```

So as you can see, both functions completely identical to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Why speculate?

Since your depth is small (i.e. 10 is small), you should run your MCVE.

Just two small changes will provide info to determine your answer:

a) cout the address of number (in addition to the value).

b) instead of a const number, fetch something that is not constant. (see below)

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>


class T595_t
{

public:

   T595_t() = default;
   ~T595_t() = default;

   int exec(int , char**)
      {
         std::cout << "\n  func1(10)" << std::flush;
         func1(10);

         std::cout << "\n  func2(10)" << std::flush;
         func2(10);


         return 0;
      }

private: // methods

   void func1(int depth)
      {
         if(depth== 0) return;
         uint64_t number(time(nullptr));
         std::cout << "\n  " << depth 
                   << " " << number << "  " << &number;
         func1(--depth);
      }

   void func2(int depth)
      {
         if(depth== 0) return;
         {
            uint64_t number(std::time(nullptr));
            std::cout << "\n  " << depth 
                      << " " << number << "  " << &number;
         }
         func2(--depth);
      }

}; // class T595_t


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   T595_t  t595;
   return  t595.exec(argc, argv);
}
```

---

With output (on Ubuntu 17.10, using g++ version 7.2.0.)

```
  func1(10)
  10 1523379410  0x7ffd449d7d90
  9 1523379410  0x7ffd449d7d60
  8 1523379410  0x7ffd449d7d30
  7 1523379410  0x7ffd449d7d00
  6 1523379410  0x7ffd449d7cd0
  5 1523379410  0x7ffd449d7ca0
  4 1523379410  0x7ffd449d7c70
  3 1523379410  0x7ffd449d7c40
  2 1523379410  0x7ffd449d7c10
  1 1523379410  0x7ffd449d7be0
  func2(10)
  10 1523379410  0x7ffd449d7d90
  9 1523379410  0x7ffd449d7d60
  8 1523379410  0x7ffd449d7d30
  7 1523379410  0x7ffd449d7d00
  6 1523379410  0x7ffd449d7cd0
  5 1523379410  0x7ffd449d7ca0
  4 1523379410  0x7ffd449d7c70
  3 1523379410  0x7ffd449d7c40
  2 1523379410  0x7ffd449d7c10
  1 1523379410  0x7ffd449d7be0
```

When unoptimized, the code gen for each funcX seems to do the same thing.  And since the code completes in less than a second, all the values (of number) are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Well, GCC 6.2.1 with -O0 produces the same assembly for both of your functions.

What closing braces do, within a single function, is determine when *destructors* are called.  For instance consider the following:

```
struct Number {
  int n;
  ~Number() { std::cout << "~" << n << ", "; }
};

void func(int depth){
    if(depth== 0) return;
    Number number{depth};
    std::cout << number.n << ", ";
    func(--depth);
}
void func2(int depth){
    if(depth== 0) return;
    {
      Number number{depth};
      std::cout << number.n << ", ";
    }
    func2(--depth);
}

int main(int, char**) {
  std::cout << "Calling func. \n";
  func(10);
  std::cout << "\n\n";
  std::cout << "Calling func1. \n";
  func2(10);
}
```

This outputs

```
Calling func.
10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, ~1, ~2, ~3, ~4, ~5, ~6, ~7, ~8, ~9, ~10,

Calling func1.
10, ~10, 9, ~9, 8, ~8, 7, ~7, 6, ~6, 5, ~5, 4, ~4, 3, ~3, 2, ~2, 1, ~1,
```

So if `number` were some `std::vector` or maybe `std::ifstream`, then yes those braces would be quite necessary.